# Application crashing on [NSIndexPath setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

```
2013-03-06 17:38:14.764 LiveiPad[506:607] -[NSIndexPath setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x57ac40
2013-03-06 17:38:14.785 LiveiPad[506:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x57ac40'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3182564f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x30229c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x318291bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
3   CoreFoundation                      0x31828649 ___forwarding___ + 508
4   CoreFoundation                      0x3179f180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   UIKit                               0x32a30a11 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 552
6   UIKit                               0x32a3076b -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 34
7   UIKit                               0x32a290cd -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 936
8   UIKit                               0x32a2827d -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 140
9   UIKit                               0x329d45fb -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 26
10  CoreFoundation                      0x31792f03 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 22
11  QuartzCore                          0x361c5bb5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 120
12  QuartzCore                          0x361c596d CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 184
13  QuartzCore                          0x361cb1c5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 212
14  QuartzCore                          0x361cafd7 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 190
15  QuartzCore                          0x361c4055 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 56
16  CoreFoundation                      0x317fca35 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
17  CoreFoundation                      0x317fe465 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
18  CoreFoundation                      0x317ff75b __CFRunLoopRun + 854
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3178fec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
20  CoreFoundation                      0x3178fdcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
21  GraphicsServices                    0x365b241f GSEventRunModal + 114
22  GraphicsServices                    0x365b24cb GSEventRun + 62
23  UIKit                               0x329fdd69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
24  UIKit                               0x329fb807 UIApplicationMain + 670
25  LiveiPad                    0x000024cb main + 158
26  LiveiPad                    0x00002428 start + 40
 )
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Does any one knows why this is crashing?
Here is some code which i am using on page control selection

```
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.svMinistatementTable.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.svMinistatementTable.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pcMinistatementDetail.currentPage = page;

        CGRect Viewframe = CGRectMake((896*self.pcMinistatementDetail.currentPage), 0, 896, 235 );
        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:Viewframe];
        subview.tag=self.pcMinistatementDetail.currentPage;
        CGRect frameTable= CGRectMake( 0, 0, 896, 235 );
        UITableView *tableView= [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame: frameTable];
        tableView.tag=self.pcMinistatementDetail.currentPage;
        tableView.dataSource=self;
        tableView.delegate=self;

        if([strCallingView isEqualToString:@"Account"])
        {
            tableviewMiniStatement=tableView;

        }
        else if([strCallingView isEqualToString:@"CreditCard"])
        {
            tableviewCCUnbilledTransaction=tableView;

        }
        [subview addSubview: tableView];
        [self.svMinistatementTable addSubview:subview];
        [tableView reloadData];code here
```

Comment: show your code? No one can help on only crash log..

Comment: crashing because you are  making NSIndexpath object to set table style

Comment: absolutely. place some related code here.

Comment: place your tableView datasource and delegate code..

Comment: The very first line of your crash says the whole story, you are calling a UITableView method on an object of NSINdexpath, it will simply crash.

Comment: What's about the exception breakpoints?

Answer (score 4):

There is no method like this in UITableView class called

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

You need to specify the style as well, whether it is plain or grouped,

the correct method is `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style;`

`UITableView *tableView= [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:frameTable style:UITableViewStylePlain];` or grouped

Comment: used the above lines but still it is crashing

Answer (score 3):

As many people said, the problem is here:

```
2013-03-06 17:38:14.764 LiveiPad[506:607] -[NSIndexPath setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x57ac40
```

You should call the `setTableViewStyle:` on a `UITableView` object, and not in an `NSIndexPath` one.

From the Dev Documents:

> Table views can have one of two styles, UITableViewStylePlain and
>   UITableViewStyleGrouped. When you create a UITableView instance you
>   must specify a table style, and this style cannot be changed.

So the problem is most likely to be when you are creating the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the Same Error While Making the Custom cell using table view

The Error was i was not Returning the cell in the CellForRowAtIndexPath :

Try Returning it your Error will be solved.